# Apache RewriteRule based on previously matched rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a set of rules for my site.

The main idea is that if the request matches rule #1 then all image requests must follow a certain rule.

If request matches rule #2 then all image requests must follow another rule.

This is what I have actually :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^folder1$ dir1 [QSA,P,C]
    RewriteRule (.*)$ images1/$1 [QSA,P,L]
    RewriteRule ^folder2$ dir2 [QSA,P,C]
    RewriteRule (.*)$ images2/$1 [QSA,P,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: My client has one DNS which he wants to redirect to 3 websites depending on a parameter :
http://website.com/1 ==> site1


http://website.com/2 ==> site2


http://website.com/3 ==> site3


The problem is that the images in the sites have relative path which are not properly resolved because of the rewriting

Comment: The DNS is pointing to the root folder of my client on the webserver (everything is properly configured and working fine)
The basic RewriteRule are working ie if I type http://website.com/3 I get redirected to the proper website. **BUT** the images are not loaded properly because the server tries to resolve http://website.com/gallery/image1.png instead of <workingdir>/gallery/images.png.

Comment: SO i need to set rules to say that if the server previously rewrited to **site3** all subsequents request must be rewrited to **folder3**